# Как сделать так чтоб block2 доходил до block3 и при этом был адаптивным

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я не понимаю как сделать так чтоб block2 со значением width 100vh дошел до block3 а не игнорировал его. Если убрать position absolute у block3, то он скроется

```css
html {
    background: black;
}

.left {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: purple;
}

.block1 {
    background: red;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.block2 {
    background: white;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-left: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.block3 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background: green;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
}

.block2_block {
    margin: 7px 50px;
    background: yellow;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>BIRDFARM</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
  <style>
input[type='number'] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {color:#fff;}
::-moz-placeholder          {color:#fff;}/* Firefox 19+ */
:-moz-placeholder           {color:#fff;}/* Firefox 18- */
:-ms-input-placeholder      {color:#fff;}
</style>
<body>
  <aside class="left">
    <div class="block1"></div>
    <div class="block2">
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
      <div class="block2_block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block3"></div>
  </aside>
  <
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а вы могли бы оставить только минимум необходимого кода?

Comment: Это и есть минимум. P.S Добавил картинку

Comment: Что подразумевается под адаптивностью?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо из 100vh вычесть высоты блок1 и блок3 и значения их margin-top/bottom, padding-top/bottom.

В вашем случае добавьте блоку2

```
height: calc(100vh - 100px /* высота .block3 */ - 200px /* высота .block1 */ - 20px /* margin-top у .block1 */);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
html {
    background: black;
}

.left {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: purple;
}

.block1 {
    background: red;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.block2 {
    background: white;
    width: 400px;
    height: calc(100vh - 100px /* высота .block3 */ - 200px /* высота .block1 */ - 20px /* margin-top у .block1 */);
    margin-left: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.block3 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background: green;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
}

.block2_block {
    margin: 7px 50px;
    background: yellow;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="block2">
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
  <div class="block2_block"></div>
</div>
<div class="block3"></div>
```